# What execCommand commands are available in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Can anyone tell me what `execCommand` commands are available in CKEditor?
Like `editor.execCommand('bold')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately commands are not specified in JSDocs.

However, every command is added to editor by `editor#addCommand` method, so you can grep the code for them:

```
> grep -R addCommand *
```

Regarding Daevo's response - toolbar config consists of buttons names - not command names. Usually each button has corresponding command, but it doesn't have to be a rule.

> Tnnks for ur rply..Is there any command to select particular text..?

There are three commands related to selection - "selectAll", "selectNextCell", "selectPreviousCell". But if you want to do custom selection take a look on Range and Selection APIs. In short - you have to create range and call `range#select` method.

Answer (score 8):

The commands that are available to you depend on the installed plugins.
This list of available CKEditor commands can be found using `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.commands`

Answer (score 2):

They can be any command. This would include all the built-in command like listed here http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Addionally and commands you or a plug-in create.

I guess the main point is to allow you to call afterCommandExec and beforeCommandExec so you can perform your own code when a button is clicked.